# alivepdf not displaying movieclip

Tags: php, actionscript-3, alivepdf

this is my actionscript code:

```
var myPDF:PDF = new PDF( Orientation.LANDSCAPE, Unit.MM, Size.A4 );

myPDF.addPage();
myPDF.addImage(printarea_mc);

saveAs_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, generatePDF );

function generatePDF (e:MouseEvent){

myPDF.save(Method.REMOTE, "create.php","MyFile.pdf");
}
```

where **printarea_mc** is my movie clip where i have all the data that i want to save.

this is my create.php:

```
<?php
$method = $_GET['method'];
$name = $_GET['name'];

if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {
        $pdf = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header('Content-Length: '.strlen($pdf));
        header('Content-disposition:'.$method.'; filename="'.$name.'"');
        echo $pdf;

}  else {
echo 'An error occured.';
}
?>
```

when i click the button to save as pdf, is going some sort of link like

```
http://... create.php?name=output.pdf&method=MyFile.pdf?%PDF-1.41%200%20obj<</Type%20/Pages/Kids%20[3%200%20R]/Count%201>>endobj3%200%20obj<</Type%20/Page/Parent%201%200%20R/MediaBox%20[0%200%20841.89%20595.28]/Resources%202%200%20R/Rotate%200/Dur%203/Contents%204%200%20R>>endobj4%200%20obj<</Filter%20/FlateDecode%20/Length%2065>>streamxÚ3Rðâ2Ð35W(çÒw%0F6PH/æ*T0µ4Ô30P
```

and it gives me the output of the else echo "An error occured."

the print_r($method); gives me

```
MyFile.pdf?%PDF-1.41 0 obj<>endobj3 0 obj<>endobj4 0 obj<>streamxÃš3RÃ°Ã¢2Ã35W(Ã§Ã’w6PH/Ã¦*T0Âµ4Ã”30P
```

and the print_r($name); output of `output.pdf`

All the import org. in actionscript is made well, and the swf it does give me no error.

what i'm doing wrong, because most certainly i do something???

Thank you

Comment: Sometimes AlivePDF throws that error when you are testing it from Flash IDE. When you export to SWF and view that SWF from a browser, sometimes it works.
Sadly, the AS3 developer's lot in life is we have to work with all kinds of confusing libraries that are not longer maintained. Good luck!

Comment: then are there some better libraries to use? or other methods to export a mc to pdf?

Comment: No you definately want to be using the latest version of AlivePDF. It is the standard for Flash PDF exporting. It can work sometimes.

Comment: hmm.. i'm using 1.4.9 (seems the stable version), but now i will try the beta or the rc, maybe i have better results